# Foreach loop in Jquery is not working

Tags: jquery

In my coding, I used Foreach loop to get the data from database and listed in the select tag.

n no of times loop is executed correctly.

foreach is not working properly. Here subjects are not getting from the database

```
 n = $("#semester").val();    
for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
{
var newTextDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
newTextDiv.attr("id", 'subject' + i);
newTextDiv.after().html('<?PHP $get_subject = $this->Cc_admin->get_active_subject(); ?><select name="add_subject'+i+'[]"><?PHPforeach($get_subject as $subject) { ?><option value = "<?PHP echo $subject['subject_id']; ?>" ><?PHP echo $subject['subject_name']; ?></option><?PHP}?></select>');
newTextDiv.appendTo("#allsemsubject");
}
```

The output comes like this

```
<select name="add_subject1[]" multiple=""><!--?PHPforeach($get_subject as $subject) { ?--><option value=""></option><!--?PHP}?--></select>
```

Comment: `<?PHPforeach` needs a space between `PHP` and `foreach`

Comment: I used `$get_subject = $this->Cc_admin->get_active_subject();` this method to get the data from the database. How I used  $.each(...)  loop

Comment: There is no PHP foreach @TiiJ7. This code is a total mess. All of the PHP must be processed server-side.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Going by his output I assume it runs through php first (the php inside the `option` is gone etc). I agree that it is a mess, though, so who knows.

Comment: my concept, In client side <select>tag is repeated n no of times. The values of the select tag is get from the database. Please help me to solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: @TiiJ7  <?PHPforeach that code. If i give space between PHP and foreach the output comes blank page.

Comment: Put a space here as well: `<?PHP}?>` between `PHP` and `}`

Answer (score 0):

Also embedding php in javascript will not work like that because you are just putting it into the source HTML on the client side.  PHP is a server-side language and needs to be processed there.

You can have PHP output JavaScript but not vice versa like you are trying.  You will want something like the $.each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re arrange the code, get your foreach printed into a string and then pass to html(). Also your code needs a bit debugging before passing string to html().

Remember to access PHP variables only in PHP code.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.